# WiX Toolset: Wrap exe in msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

We have an exe that we would like to wrap in an MSI so that it can be deployed via GPO. One caveat is that it is highly preferred that the generated installer does not require user interaction (i.e. no final checkbox to launch the exe after install). For clarity, I'm doing this from OSX using the following Docker Container: https://github.com/suchja/wix-toolset

I have the following .wxs: https://pastebin.com/AeMfTzvd

I'm running the following commands:

`wix/candle.exe app/config.wxs
wix/light.exe -sval -v -ext WixUtilExtension Mark43CAD.wixobj`

Everything seems to compile correctly, but when I attempt to run the msi on a Windows machine I am getting the following error:

[image]

I can't seem to find anything useful when I tail the logs during the installation? Is there a simpler way to configure wix to allow me to deploy this exe as an msi?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the corruption error, but I'd change your custom action to  Execute="commit" so that it will only run after a successful install. Also, you'll want to condition the action so that it doesn't run during an uninstall. Maybe something like this: <Custom Action='LaunchInstalledExe' After='InstallFinalize'>&MainApplication=3 Or (!MainApplication=3 And REINSTALL)</Custom>